# IsClipboardFormatAvailable returns true but GetClipboardData returns NULL even when text on clipboard

Tags: winapi, vim

This is a problem I only see in vim but I am hoping someone can provide advice on what to look for (with google code shutdown, I cannot submit bug reports for vim).

On x64 Windows 8.1 (it works fine on x64 Windows 7) vim/gvim works fine with the windows clipboard until you launch a web browser (chrome, firefox, opera, ie).  When the browser is running, vim can place text on the clipboard but cannot get text from the clipboard.  When the web browser is closed, the clipboard starts working again.

I have tracked the problem down to IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning non-NULL but GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning NULL under these conditions.  It seems to be something specific to how vim is using the win32 api (probably different calls than these) because simple test apps that I write doing this work fine.

I have tried running with different compatibility settings and running as administrator but nothing makes a difference.  This behavior is the same for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds created using Visual Studio 2013 Community and 2010 Professional.

What is the most puzzling is that the official 32-bit build (very old at this point) works fine but my own build off of the exact same tag (or every other build I have found on the internet) does not work.

For the curious there are instructions on how to get and build vim on windows here (note - I am not the blog author): http://solar-blogg.blogspot.com/p/vim-build.html

Comment: Why don't you talk about this on the vim_dev mailing list?

Comment: I tried that, it bounced.  I think everything went down with google code.

Comment: The last message was sent by Bram himself nine hours ago.

Comment: `"GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning non-NULL but GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning NULL"` - perhaps you meant `"IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning TRUE but GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT) returning NULL"` instead?

Comment: Thanks, I editted to say IsClipboardFormatAvailable returns non-NULL

Comment: Search for [`#ifdef _WIN64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) (or similar)  in the source base and you have found the bug.